# how to use Like in query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I wants to use like query with a string value,. I have written like this , '_' is for accepting a character from string. But it doesn't works. Is the query string correct ? please help .

```
userName = nvc["user_name"];

string userName_Remove_First = userName.Substring(1); //Removes the first character of userName 
string Last = userName_Remove_First.Remove(userName_Remove_First.Length - 1); //Removes the last character of userName_Remove_First

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select student_id,student_name from student_details where student_id   LIKE ('"+last+"_') ", con);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Assumming `Last` contains eg 'ABC', your SQL statement will return any record where student_id has 4 letters, the first three of which are `ABC`. If that's not what you want, what result did you expect?

Comment: @Arathy can you explain us with an example ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can use **[Like Query](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)**

The following SQL statement selects all Employee with Name starting with the letter "s":

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
WHERE EmployeeName LIKE 's%';
```

with respect to above example  i have slightly modified you query

```
 string cmd = select student_id,student_name from student_details where student_id  
 LIKE ('"+Last+"%') and len(student_id) = "+Last.Length+1;
```

So if your table has records  `HALF,HALFER,HAF,HAG` and your username is `AHAR` then your  OP will be   `HAF,HAG`

Comment: point the mistake in OP's query and this will be a good answer

Comment: %will accept any number of letters. But I only needs to one character extra. Thats why used '_' @Kyle

Comment: What do you mean one character extra ?? It would be good if you could explain with the help of an example

Comment: if string Last="HA"; then query should accept a word starting with "HA" and ending with only one character, Ex: HAI,HAM,HAS etc. shouldnt accept the words like  HAAAL,HAAAI etc..

Comment: @Kyle as ARATHY has said he does not want to match against `LIKE '%Jo%'` as this can return many results longer than 3 characters where as `LIKE 'Jo_'` will only return results with 3 characters the first being `Jo`

Comment: So what doesn't work? The original query should work if `Last` contains HA and there *are* any records with Student_ID like HAI, HAM, HAS. Are there perhaps any whitespaces in the student_id? Newlines? Does running the SQL command in SQL Management Studio return any results?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select student_id,student_name from student_details where student_id   LIKE "+last+"_", con);
```

Comment: The SQL Injection is still there

Comment: need the single quotes around the `'"+last+"_'"`

Comment: ...and the LIKE argument seems to miss its single quotes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, that has been pointed out already. The question was not how to stop SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to find students whose `student_id` starts with the contents of `Last`, you can execute this query:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("select student_id,student_name from student_details where student_id   LIKE @term", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term",Last + "%");
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

If you only need students whose ID is as long as `Last` plus 1 more character you can use

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term",Last + "_");
```

Comment: AddWithValue is not getting

Comment: Oops, fixed it. Anyway, does running the SQL command in SSMS return anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this This:

```
string last= "A";
Select * from Students Where StudentID LIKE '"%+last+"'
```

OR
    Select * from Students Where StudentID LIKE '"+last+%"'